# How can i create a UI for each tab of a tabbed activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm learning developing for android but i don't know how to create the UI for a Fragment.
I created a new activity and during the creation process I selected the navigation type "Tabs + Swipe".
Now i have a layout xml which i can't modify using the WYSIWYG interface and if i -for example- create a button widget using java in the class file it creates it in every "tab view".

I basically want to create different interfaces for every tab (fragment).

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In just created Activity you can find inner class `SectionsPagerAdapter`. Look at this method:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

This method for every tab returns instance of DummySectionFragment with only different bundles. If you want to create fragments with different views for every tab you should check value of `i` variable and according to this value create proper fragment. For example:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment; 
    switch(i){
    case 0:
         fragment = new MyFragment1();
         break;
    case 1:
         fragment = new MyFragment2();
         break;
    case 3:
         fragment = new MyFragment3();
         break;
    default:
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid section number");
    }

    //set args if necessary
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}
```

Instead of `DummySectionFragment` class create three classes: MyFragment1, MyFragment2, MyFragment2 and for each, inside method `onCreateView` create or inflate view, for example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment1.xml, null);
    return v;
```

}

Where R.layout.my_fragment1.xml is layout of your MyFragment1 fragment.

Comment: do the fragment sub classes have to be `static`?

Comment: If you ask about MyFragment1, MyFragment2 etc, these are just public classes that extend `Fragment`, each in separated java file.